# ionic - iFrame iOS issue

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iframe, ionic-framework

at the moment I have an issue regarding implementing an iFrame into my ionic app. Everything is working if I open the Page, where the iFrame is embeded, on Android. But if I open the page on iOS I get an error in my console which says:

*Blocked a frame with origin "http://mywebsite.com" from accessing a frame with origin "file://". The frame requesting has protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.*

How can I fix this issue? Do I have to make changes on the Page which I'm trying to embed or do I have to change something within the app?

Best regards and thanks

Comment: Don't use an iframe?

Comment: Is there an other way in Ionic to implement an external Page?